# SMF.UI.showDatePicker Showing Wrong Date

Tags: smartface.io

I'm not getting the selected date, but the emulator's system date. Tried publishing and installing on actual Samsung S6, same it's showing system date not selected date. Is there something wrong with my code below?

```
function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e)
{
   SMF.UI.showDatePicker({onSelect:DoSomething});
}
function DoSomething(e)
{
   alert(e.date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some missing but that is not the actual problem. You are probably trying to select a date from past. There is a problem about that and will be fixed with the next release.

By the way I suggest you to use datePicker as in the documents (http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_SMF_UI_showDatePicker.htm).

You should add mask, minDate and maxDate values, etc. 
But as I said, although you add these values to your project, it will not work now. The problem will be fixed with the next release.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed one thing, when I publish to android 4.x phones, it works correctly (showing selected date), but on android 5.x, it doesn't (showing system instead of selected date).